# how to conform appdelegate to protocol PTChannelManagerDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, ios16

I'm building a iOS application using flutter , I'm looking to integrate IOS PushToTalk framework in the application , I have setup the pushtotalk iOS framework in appdelegate.swift file .On building the app , I am getting the error :  Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'PTChannelManagerDelegate'

The appdelegate.swift code is mentioned below

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import awesome_notifications
import shared_preferences_ios
import PushToTalk
import AVFoundation
@UIApplicationMain
 @objc class AppDelegate:FlutterAppDelegate,PTChannelManagerDelegate,PTChannelRestorationDelegate{
    
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        
        
     var channelManager  = try await PTChannelManager.channelManager(delegate: self,restorationDelegate: self)

        
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    

     @objc
     func channelManager(channelManager:PTChannelManager, channelUUID: UUID, didBeginTransmittingFrom: PTChannelTransmitRequestSource)
    {

    }
    @objc
     func channelManager(channelManager:PTChannelManager, channelUUID: UUID, didEndTransmittingFrom: PTChannelTransmitRequestSource)
    {

    }
    @objc
      func channelManager(channelManager: PTChannelManager, failedToBeginTransmittingInChannel: UUID, error: (any Error)?)
    {

    }
   @objc
      func channelManager(channelManager:PTChannelManager, failedToStopTransmittingInChannel: UUID, error: (any Error)?)
    {

    }
   @objc
       func channelManager(_ channelManager:PTChannelManager, didJoinChannel: UUID, reason: PTChannelJoinReason)
    {

    }
    @objc
      func channelManager(_ channelManager:PTChannelManager, didLeaveChannel: UUID, reason: PTChannelLeaveReason)
    {

    }
    @objc
      func channelManager(channelManager:PTChannelManager, failedToJoinChannel: UUID, error: (any Error)?)
    {

    }
    @objc
      func channelManager(channelManager:PTChannelManager, failedToLeaveChannel: UUID, error: (any Error)?)
    {

    }
   @objc
      func channelManager(_ channelManager:PTChannelManager, receivedEphemeralPushToken: Data)
    {

    }
   @objc
       func incomingPushResultForChannelManager(
        channelManager: PTChannelManager,
        channelUUID: UUID,
        pushPayload: [String : Any]
    ) -> PTPushResult
    {
        return .leaveChannel

    }
    @objc
    func channelDescriptor(restoredChannelUUID channelUUID: UUID) -> PTChannelDescriptor
    {}

}
```

on building the app , I get the error
Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'PTChannelManagerDelegate'

Comment: There are 11 methods in the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushtotalk/ptchannelmanagerdelegate and it looks like your AppDelegate does conform to them. I wonder if you might need `@objc` on your extension declaration, or move the extension functions to the main AppDelegate declaration.

Comment: i have implementedf the required methods from the documentation , ill try the suggestion with objc keyword and moving the extension functions to main appdelegate

Comment: @Chris I tried ur suggestions still the same error

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. Should the `@UIApplicationMain` be there? Is that not for main app entry point rather than App Delegate?

Comment: according to the documentation , I should be declaring the channel manager instance as soon as the app has been launched,